# Syntax in OCaml : passing array after modification

Tags: ocaml

I'm having a hard figuring out what to do with this code, that does not compile correctly. I'm trying to write a DP version for the knapsack problem. I want to keep track of previous solution for the sub-problems, by keeping them in memory, using a matrix called *mem*. I want to initialize all values to be -1 (i.e. *not computed yet*), except for the edge conditions, i.e for backpack weight of 0 or 0 items. Therefore, I initialize the matrix at -1 and change its values at edge conditions. But I don't know how to pass the *mem* array after that to the next part of the code. I tried using **in** or **and** but it doesn't work.

Help greatly appreciated!

```
let knapsack_mem = fun (vps : (int * int) array) (c : int) -> 
let mem = Array.make_matrix (c + 1) ((Array.length vps) + 1) (-1) in
mem.(0) <- Array.make (n + 1) 0; for i = 1 to c do mem.(i).(0) <- 0;

(* HERE : in ? and ? *)

let rec aux vps (i,j) = 
    if mem.(i).(j) >= 0 then mem.(i).(j)
    else 
        if lst vps.(i) <= i then max ((aux vps (i - lst vps.(i), j - 1)) + fst vps.(i)) (aux vps (i, j - 1)) 
        else aux vps (i,j - 1)
in aux vps (c, (Array.length vps) + 1) ;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error you are getting is due to the use of the for loop. The syntax is the [following](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/if_statements_loops_and_recursion.html#For-loops-and-while-loops):

```
for i = 1 to n_jobs () do
    do_next_job ()
done
```

Since this is a side effect operation don't forget to use a ; after the "done" to continue the body of the function. There are other problems with your code but this should fix the syntax error.